# Java, fill CSV File with integer casted to String

Tags: java, csv

I have an Integer value that is to long to be exported and displayed correctly in a CSV file.

the value is diaplyed like this:

```
1,13364E+12
```

instead of something like this:

```
08136677950770
```

I use BufferedWriter to write the file, and the code looks like this:

```
writer.write(data[0].toString());
writer.write(";");
```

I've tried like this:

```
writer.write("\'"+data[0].toString()+"\'");
writer.write(";");
```

but it displays this:

```
'08136677950770'
```

How can I display this value without the quotes?

```
08136677950770
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your solutions, but none of them worked.

I've found the solution that consist to add the simple Tab character (/t ASCII 9) at the end:

```
writer.write(data[0].toString()+"\t");
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you using the [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), that works with the `String` representation.

To get its value use simple `toString()` method.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1234567890"); 
String str = bi.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use microsoft excel or some application program to open the csv and it shows this way 1,13364E+12 .
It doesn't mean the value has changed. It is excel that has formatted it the way it like. But the value is still the same.

You can use ordinary notepad to open it and see the actual value.

Again try changing

```
writer.write("\'"+data[0].toString()+"\'");
```

to

```
writer.write("\""+data[0].toString()+"\"");
```

OR to this if it doesn't work.

```
writer.write(data[0].toString()+"");
```